# How do you get the equation of motion of a spherical pendulum WITHOUT using Lagrange or Hamilton equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

How do you get the equation of motion of a [spherical pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum) WITHOUT using Lagrange or Hamilton equation? I have been searching for a proper explanation but all websites use Lagrangian and I don't know that. Can anyone give me a link or something?

Comment: Start by writing Newton's laws and see what you get.

Comment: It is done in Newtonian form in lots of books including Marion and Thorten, and it is not hard, but it *is* harder to extract the really interesting physics from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is very easy (computations are not so easy if you are not familiar with curvilinear coordinates): Write down $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$ using the basis $\hat{r}, \hat{\theta}, \hat{\varphi}$ associated to spherical coordinates  and next project that vectorial equation along the  basis of vectors tangent to the sphere, $\hat{\theta}, \hat{\varphi}$. The two equations you find this way do not contain the unknown reaction due to the sphere, as it is normal to it by hypotheses. This pair of equations is the same as the one obtained within the Lagrangian approach.
You have two degrees of freedom and a system of two differential equations which can be proved to satisfy the theorem of existence and uniqueness and thus it determines the motion of the pendulum.  As a matter of fact this procedure is nothing but what Lagrangian mechanics automatically does.

Answer (score 1):

To work this problem you should start by knowing that $L_z$ component of angular momentum is conserved (as always, if all the forces are parallel to $z$ or if their prolongation meets the $z$ axis: a theorem guarantees this: I won't write the proof here, if this starting point confuses you should search for axial angular momentum: anyway you don't need Lagrange or Hamilton formalism to proof this). Knowing that, we have two constants of motion
\begin{equation}
 E= \frac{1}{2} m v^2 - mgz \qquad L_z = m (x v_y - y v_x)
\end{equation}
We have only two degree of fredom (the point is moving on a surface), so two equations and two unknows, a good starting point. Let's work the problem. Obiouvsly it is useful to use spherical coordinates taking as origin the center of the sphere:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = l \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
y = l \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
z = l \cos \theta
\end{cases}
$$
Taking derivative we get
$$
\begin{cases}
v_x = l \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \cos \phi - l \dot{\phi} \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
v_y = l \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \sin \phi + l \dot{\phi} \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
v_z = - l \dot{\theta} \sin \theta
\end{cases}
$$
exploiting repeatedly the fundamental equation of trigonometry we get
$$
v^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2 = l^2 (\dot{\theta}^2 + \dot{\phi}^2 \sin^2 \theta)
$$
So the two constants of motion can be writtem
$$
E= \frac{1}{2} m l^2 (\dot{\theta}^2 + \dot{\phi}^2 \sin^2 \theta) - mgl\cos \theta  \qquad  L_z = m l^2 \dot{\phi} \sin^2 \theta 
$$
Taking $\dot{\phi}$ and doing substitution we get
$$
E = \frac{1}{2} m l^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{L_z^2}{2ml^2 \sin^2 \theta} - mgl \cos \theta
$$
Taking time derivative we get this equation of motion
$$
ml\ddot{\theta} = \frac{L_z^2 \cos \theta}{m l^3 \sin^3 \theta} - mg \sin \theta
$$
please note that this differential equation involve only $\theta$: it allows (in principle) to find $\theta=\theta(t)$, by knowing this we can find $\phi=\phi(t)$ with the other differential equation ($L_z = m l^2 \dot{\phi} \sin^2 \theta$). In general you will need a numerical approach to explore solutions of this problem (you must exploit the power of calculus of computer: pen, paper and creativity aren't sufficient), but if $\theta_\textrm{min} \approx \theta_\textrm{max}$  you can find analytically that the ratio between the period of $\theta=\theta(t)$ and the time that increase $\phi=\phi(t)$ by $2\pi$ is $\frac{T_\phi}{T_\theta} = \sqrt{1+3\cos^2 \bar{\theta}}$ (being $\bar{\theta}$ the angle $\theta_\textrm{min} \approx \theta_\textrm{max}$). So if the motion is near the bottom $T_\phi \approx 2 T_\theta$ (i.e. the general motion near the bottom will look like an "ellipse", with two high points and two low  points each revolution).